# Subplots with dates: missing parts of the graph when sharing the same X-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization, boxplot

I want to create twp subplots with a boxplot at the top and a bar chart at the bottom. 
The boxplot covers the data for 12 months for the last 10 years while the bar chart covers only 5 months of this year as there is no further data available.

**My code:**

```
#Visualise the data
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="whitegrid")

f, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharey=True, sharex=True)

ax.plot= sns.boxplot(x="Month", y='application_number', data=results_df_groupby_truncated_monthly_dataframe, fliersize=5, ax=axes[0])

ax.plot= sns.barplot(x="Month", y='application_number', data=results_df_groupby_truncated_pandemic_monthly_dataframe, ax=axes[1])
```

**Output -A**

I used `sharex=True` because sharing the same x-axis helps to compare the two graphs. However, the boxplot does not show all the 12 months but only 5 months. The colours of the bar chart do not match with the box plot.

[image]

**Output -B**

I  used `sharex=False`. The boxplot shows all the 12 months but it is no easy to make a comparison between the two graphs. The colours of the bar chart do not match with the box plot.

[image]

**Desired output**:

[image]

Any idea of how to 1)align the two charts with the same x-axis, 2)match the colours of both graphs, 3) show 12 months? Many thanks.

Comment: Axes[0].set_xlim(0, 12)?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve all three goals by using the `order` parameter of `sns.boxplot` and `sns.barplot`. This has the effect of aligning the color of your palette and adjusting the x-axis to show all levels that you pass to `order`:

```py
# df1 contains mock data for 12 months and df2 contains mock data for 5 months

f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
sns.boxplot(x="month", y="data", order=range(1, 12), ax=ax[0], data=df1)
sns.barplot(x="month", y="data", order=range(1, 12), ax=ax[1], data=df2)
```

[image]